# Karma.conf.js load files before starting Chrome

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-chrome-launcher

If I run my tests with `browsers: ['PhantomJS'],` the tests pass but if I run with browsers: ['Chrome'], then it says `google is not defined` I think because it is loading the Chrome browser before the files in the karma.conf.js files field. How do I load the files before karma starts Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Not THE answer...but changing to use [IE](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ie-launcher) makes it work...

It might be because it is slower to load

However IE doesn't make the test folders visible like Chrome does so cannot debug in IE.